# Button does not center inside RelativeLayout that have gravity=center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button inside relative layout that I want to center along with input edit text. I added `android:gravity="center"`  to relative layout, every was centered correctly other than the button, I even tried to add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to the button but it didn't work. What could be the issue?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
        android:text="Login"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<View
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Button is not centered:

[image]

Comment: your `LinearLayout` has two child that has weight, if you set gravity to center,you just make view in center of that child not hole screen

Comment: the relative layout has weight and fill parent in width, and I want to center every child inside the relative layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:gravity="center"` is a property of `LinearLayout` so its direct child (the `RelativeLayout`) inside of it. You still need to center the children inside the `RelativeLayout`. To center the `Button` inside of its parent `RelativeLayout` use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>   // here
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerHorizontal)

**Update**

Center each `View` inside of the `RelativeLayout`

```
 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: So what happened, your `Button` didn't move? That should have worked

Comment: Hmmm...it worked for me by removing `gravity` from the `RelativeLayout` then putting `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in each of the 3 `View`s of the `RelativeLayout`. Then they are all centered. Try that

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue with that is I want to center all children combined of relative layout in the middle of its view (horizontally and vertically), and thats why I need to use gravity.

Comment: If you looked at this picture, my relative layout is the gray area and the white area is where the children are centered http://projecteuler.net/project/images/p_173_square_laminas.gif

Comment: I actually did have `gravity` in the `RelativeLayout` when I tried it and it worked for me unless I just don't understand what you want. But that centered all of the children in the `RelativeLayout` and that should be centered in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You got it right, for some reason I thought the gravity was not there at first. kudus to you for spending the time to test it and answer.

Comment: I didn't have the `gravity` at first so that was my fault then I edited. Sorry, had several things going on. Glad its working for you. They was that the children needed to be told to be centered in their direct parent (the `RelativeLayout`). The `gravity` in the `RelativeLayout` only applies to its overall position in its direct parent (the `LinearLayout`) not its children.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..  Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
        android:text="Login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

OR in Your same layout just remove `android:gravity="center"` add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for each `EditText` and `Button`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The reason I use gravity=center instead of setting each view to center, is that gravity treats all children as one and centered in the relative layout both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Login"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<View
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```